# Wrong Keyboard map on Qt apps running over Wayland server

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, qt, wayland

I'm trying to execute a Qt app (https://www.mudlet.org/) over Wayland on a clean Ubuntu 17.10 installation. The app is working well except by the keyboard layout. My main language is Spanish and all the system is working well with the Spanish language.

Starting session over **xorg** works well without any problem. I have only this problem starting gnome session with **Wayland**.

**Update**: For example:  When I type ñ in a text field , it results in ; . But only happens in Qt programs.

Comment: Could you update the question to provide a specific example of the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't result in a ; , i.e. a semicolon? (That would happen if the English (US) layout is applied for some reason.)

Comment: Similar problem found at https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/1293

Comment: If you switch the keyboard layout to a different layout and then back to Spanish, does it start working? It did when I tried it so it may be a possible workaround until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Hi @gsxruk. I probed it but the problem persists. It same that the Qt program only works with the default keyboard layout. Only with the 'old' xorg I can make it work succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed *kate*, which is a qt text editor, on Ubuntu 17.10, and have no problem to use the Spanish keyboard layout when typing.

Possibly you have spotted some kind of Wayland bug, and then it should be reported as such.

Considering that Ubuntu 18.04 will be shipped with Xorg sessions enabled by default, and not Wayland, you may want to simply start logging in to 17.10 using Xorg from now on as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you Gunnar. One question...  Is your current 17.10 a clean installation or a disto upgrade? . In my previous Ubuntu 17.10 (before a hard disk failure) was an upgrade and all was working successfully.

Comment: @bLuEdDy: It's an upgrade. I don't have access to a clean 17.10 install.